# What does “es” mean in this sentence?

Tags: pronoun, expletiva, grammar-identification

> Heute machen wir **es** uns zu Hause gemütlich.

I am just beginning study Deutsch. My understanding of this sentence is:

> Today we make us comfortable at home.

I don’t know why there is an *es*. It confuses me.
Is there a special meaning or just as a auxiliary word or a pronoun?

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. If you have any remaining questions on how it works, consult the [help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Es** is a fill-in substantive used when you are in desperate need of a subject or object, but there isn't one. Take the simpler sentence

> Wir machen **es** gemütlich.

*We make **it** comfortable.*

See the **es** in the English sentence? In both German and English, *es* is the direct object, and required.

> Wir machen es uns gemütlich.

*We make us comfortable.*

German and English differ about who is the direct object. English thinks *us* is the direct object because it is made comfortable. German instead still thinks *es* is the direct object, because the surroundings are made *gemütlich* ("pleasing") to *uns* (which is the indirect object).

So this is all about a different view what "gemütlich machen" means.

Comment: There actually is a name for this. Such "dummy pronoms", that are needed to construct a valid sentence, are called [Expletivum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum) (German) or [syntactic expletive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive) (English). So, not every expletive has four letters ;) Another example that directly translates to English (and French, btw) would be "es regnet" - "it rains" - "il pleut". There's no actual "it" doing the raining, but you have to have a subject.

Comment: @Henning Kockerbeck: It was interesting to know German *in general* doesn't need such an *Expletivum* at the many occasions English needs it but at this occasion it does while English does not. I never thought too much about this before.

Comment: Wow, thanks very much. Does it means, "Today we make it comfortable to us." ? and make it comfortable to us = make us comfortable? Is there any other examples like this?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. In English, indirect objects are rarely used. Only if some person really *receives* something. In German, they are used when something is *done for someone*, too. English uses a prepositional object or changes the direct object instead.

Comment: I wouldn’t be sure whether it is truly an expletive; I thought the expletive *es* was to fill the *Vorfeld* if there is nothing else to fill it with e.g. ‘Es wird gefeiert’ (compare ‘Hier wird gefeiert’ — no subject). (CC @HenningKockerbeck).

Comment: German in general does not need an Expletive for the subject. Only for direct objects. In English it's the other way around.

Comment: It looks like there are varying views on what an Expletive is. [The Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Expletiv) calls any "für den Sinn des Satzes entbehrliches Wort" an Expletive, even if it doesn't fullfil a grammatical function ("Ob er *wohl* Zeit hat?"). [Other sources](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gruwi.ansicht?v_typ=o&v_id=3750) maintain a stricter definition.